# Apache2 SetEnvIfNoCase using Request_URI

Tags: php, regex, apache2

i'm trying to set locale environment variables in my VHost on an apache server, so that the requested path will define the locale used.
The requirement is to use a more "consumer friendly" locale code, rather than the ISO format - but we need to map those to the supported ISO format in the framework.

For example:
`http://site.com/uk/path/to/page.html`  will set the environment variable of `REQ_LOCALE=en_GB`

And we want to default this to US english if an unexpected locale is found.

What i'm trying to use at the moment is the apache `SetEnvIfNoCase` directive in this manner:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     ^/eu     REQ_LOCALE=en_US
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     ^/es     REQ_LOCALE=es_ES
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     ^/de     REQ_LOCALE=de_DE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     ^/fr     REQ_LOCALE=fr_FR
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     ^/it     REQ_LOCALE=it_IT
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     ^/uk     REQ_LOCALE=en_GB
SetEnvIf REQ_LOCALE      ^$       REQ_LOCALE=en_US
```

For some reason only the last directive is being called. However if I remove the `^/` from the regexes the `de` one is *always* called.

So.. i'm at a bit of a loss with this now :)

Can anyone help?
(NB: I've tried using `REQUEST_URI` as well as `Request_URI` - to no change in the result)

**EDIT**
I think that the following rewrite rule could be causing my issue:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Looking at the rewritelog - it seems that this is causing a redirect and the environment variable isn't being carried across.
So...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
# initialize the env var to en_US
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     "^"     REQ_LOCALE=en_US

# now set it conditionally
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     "^/eu"  REQ_LOCALE=en_US
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     "^/es"  REQ_LOCALE=es_ES
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     "^/de"  REQ_LOCALE=de_DE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     "^/fr"  REQ_LOCALE=fr_FR
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     "^/it"  REQ_LOCALE=it_IT
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI     "^/uk"  REQ_LOCALE=en_GB
```

**EDIT:** Can you chanege your rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^ index.php?lc=%{ENV:REQ_LOCALE} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: hmm, When i applied your code the `REQ_LOCALE` was constantly set to `en_US` - it didn't seem to be doing the conditional stuff.
It almost looks as though the `REQUEST_URI` value isn't populated, or if it is it's not populated with what I think it's populated with.

Comment: What was your full URL?

Comment: I was pondering if the fact that i'm using mod_Rewrite with the code `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` could be a factor

Comment: See my EDIT to check what you get in `$_GET['lc']` inside `index.php`

Comment: Ah, that works - sorta - but that also means any additional query strings don't get passed through.

Comment: AH! I found what i was looking for in the server variable `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REQ_LOCALE']` - so i've put a bit of code in to map that out.

Comment: Yes that's true inside PHP you need to use: `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REQ_LOCALE']` for this value.